# Configure Fail over SMTP Sever in JBoss Fuse 6.1.0

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

I am trying to add one more SMTP server as a fail over Server.
Currently I have configured One mail server details and added in System Properties and sending mail Transport.
Is it possible using configuration file ?

Comment: JBoss Fuse 6.1.0 is old Fuse version, but no Fuse version has _special_ SMTP handling. Please check https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/mail-component.html if you use Camel SMTP component.

Comment: Yes,I am using Apache camel CFX but dont know how to configure fail over smtp server.